# Generic in verilog from a vhdl programmer

Tags: syntax, vhdl, verilog

What's the equivalent of the generic in verilog?
For example

```
entity my_entity
generic(a : integer);
port(x : in std_logic; y out std_logic);
end entity my_entity;
```

What's the equivalent for generic?
Also what's the equivalent for the if generate and for generate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generics are called parameters in Verilog. They are declared within the module by lines like:

```
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8;
parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 8;
```

An instantiation may individually refine the parameter values:

```
my_ram_impl #( 
  .DATA_WIDTH(16), 
  .ADDR_WIDTH(8)
)
ram_instance(
  .clk(clk),
  .addr(addr),
  .data(data),
  .cs(cs),
  .we(we)
);
```

Use these directives similar to C for conditional synthesis:

```
`ifdef  SYM
   ...
`else
   ...
`endif
```

or, more flexibly `generate` constructs like:

```
generate
  if(cond)
    ...
  else
    ...
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to use for generate to instantiate modules, core_top in this case. NCORE is a parameter into the parent module or a localparam specifying the number of cores to instantiate.

```
  wire clk;
  wire [31:0] data_from_core[0:NCORES-1];

  genvar core;
  generate
    for (core=0; core < NCORES; core=core+1) begin : core_gen
         core_top
            #(.CORE_ID  (core),
              .NCORES   (NCORES))
           u_fpgaminer_top
             (.clk_in          (clk),
              .data_out        (data_from_core[core]));
      end
  endgenerate
```